# `echo` is stripping newlines in Bash script

Tags: bash, echo

If I have a file containing newlines, the below script will output the file as is, with newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=$(cat filename.yaml)
echo "$FOO"
```

but

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=$(cat filename.yaml)
FOO=$(echo $FOO)
echo "$FOO"
```

outputs the file all on one line. How come?

Comment: `$(echo "$FOO")` perhaps?

Comment: read about word splitting in bash

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend storing the contents of entire files in a single variable.  In my experience that can have unpredictable results.

```
/usr/bin/env bash -x
index=$(wc -l filename.yaml | cut -d' ' -f1)
count=1

next () {
[[ "${count}" -lt "${index}" ]] && main
[[ "${count}" -eq "${index}" ]] && exit 0
}

main () {
line=$(sed -n "${count}p" filename.yaml)
echo "var${count}=${line}" >> varfile
count=$(($count+1))
next
}

next
```

If you source varfile at the start of another script, it will give you every line from that file, in its' own variable.